# Why weak pointer is getting created with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, move

I have written following simple code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    Foo()      { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n";  }
    ~Foo()     { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar\n";  }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> p1(new Foo);//this line

    p1->bar();

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> p2(p1);
}
```

And in watch window I got,

```
p2  std::__1::shared_ptr<Foo>   ptr = 0x100104350 strong=2 weak=1   
p1  std::__1::shared_ptr<Foo>   ptr = 0x100104350 strong=2 weak=1
```

Now, I can understand strong=2, but why weak = 1?

Secondly, in code I changed code to,

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> p1(std::move(new Foo));
```

Because, may be one weak pointer is because of nameless object. So I have moved it while creating p1, still I get same output in watch window.

Please suggest which point I am missing?

Comment: Reminder.. std::move is not magical, it's basically just a cast.  And the type of `new Foo` is `Foo*`.  There is no benefit to moving a raw pointer, there's nothing to move.  So it's a copy anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value shown for `weak` is not the number of `weak_ptr` objects that exist, it is the "weak count".

The typical `shared_ptr` implementation (originating in Boost) stores two counts in the control block, a strong count, `S`, which is the number of active `shared_ptr` objects and a weak count, `W`, which is the number of active `weak_ptr` objects + `(S != 0)`

So if there are any `shared_ptr` objects then W will always be non-zero.

The reason for this is that the implementation destroys the owned object when `S == 0` and destroys the control block when `W == 0`

Since you don't want to destroy the control block while there are `shared_ptr` objects using it, `W` must not reach 0 while there are active `shared_ptr` objects.

Comment: That means bool(S) is true(1), that is why I am getting 1.

Comment: number of `shared_ptr` objects is two, so `S=2`, number of `weak_ptr` objects is zero, so `W = 0 + (S!=0) = 0 + 1 = 1`